# How to preserve raw XML / HTML and its formatting inside of a PRE-tag

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, pre

When I choose "**View page source**" on a certain blog post of my site, I see the correct result:

```
<variable name="myPublicVar" type="String">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExamplePublic" />
</variable>
<accessor name="myAccessor" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="MetadataTest">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExampleGetter" />
</accessor>
<method name="myMethod" declaredBy="MetadataTest" returnType="void">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExampleMethod" />
</method>
<metadata name="CustomMeta">
  <arg key="param1" value="foo" />
  <arg key="param2" value="bar "/>
</metadata>
```

But when I use jQuery to replace each '<' and '>' to '&lt;' and '&gt;' respectively, the rendered result by the browser (in Chrome) messes up the self-closing elements:

```
<variable name="myPublicVar" type="String">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExamplePublic">
</metadata></variable>
<accessor name="myAccessor" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredby="MetadataTest">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExampleGetter">
</metadata></accessor>
<method name="myMethod" declaredby="MetadataTest" returntype="void">
  <metadata name="MemberMetaExampleMethod">
</metadata></method>
<metadata name="CustomMeta">
  <arg key="param1" value="foo">
  <arg key="param2" value="bar ">
</arg></arg></metadata>
```

Notice how the `<metadata>` elements unnecessarily generates a closing tag, and how the two `<arg>` elements in the last one incorrectly generates closing tags that are actually wrapping up one `<arg>` into another `<arg>`.

The conversion I use happens in this section of jQuery / JavaScript code:

```
$('pre.raw').each( function(pIndex, pDIV) {
  pDIV.innerHTML = pDIV.innerHTML.replace(/\</g, "&lt;").replace(/\>/g, "&gt;");
});
```

What could be done to stop the code from being parsed? I'm not certain whether the browser is to blame, jQuery or JavaScript?

*NOTE: Although I was having this problem in Wordpress and I could ask this in the `wordpress.stackexchange.com` site, I think this is a generic problem that can be found in various web development scenarios.*

Answer (score 2):

Escape the characters **before** adding them to the document in the first place. Don't ask the browser to generate a DOM from invalid HTML, then generate HTML from the resulting DOM, then try to fix the HTML and put it back.

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding more and more that this is the way to go. I've started another question on the Wordpress.stackexchange.com site to ask how to easily replace content of only certain elements in the post content. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/34401/9710